# Backbone.js: compare model attributes in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection of unlimited scope (can be 0, can be 1000, can be a million).  I need to search the attributes of every model in the collection and return the attributes (and their values) that are the same.

For example, if I have the following three models in the collection:

```
modelOne:
  color: "red"
  age: 10
  size: "large"

modelTwo:
  color: "red"
  age: 11
  size: "medium"

modelThree:
  color: "red"
  age: 9
  size: "large"
```

I need the app to return `color: "red"` (or some other derivation that can be parsed), since it is the only attribute that is equal across all three models.

**Edit** John Munsch's solution worked very well, but now the requirements have changed in that some attributes can now be arrays.  Is there a way to compare regular attributes, *and* attributes that are arrays?

New code example:

```
modelOne:
  color: "red"
  age: 10
  sizes: ["small", "large"]

modelTwo:
  color: "red"
  age: 9
  sizes: ["small", "large"]
```

Comment: Post a new question please if you have another thing to ask

Comment: @tkone Really? Even if it's just a variant of the same question? That seems strange to me.

Comment: @Kevin Whitaker I'm not clear what the commonality would be in this case if the two arrays were "sizes: ["small, "large"]" and "sizes: ["small"]". Is the commonality nothing in that case or is it "sizes: ["small"]" because they both have a small size red?

Comment: @John Munsch - they need to match 100%, so only ["small", "large"] would match.  ["small", "large"], ["small"] would not be a common set, at least per the requirements of what I'm working on.

Comment: @JohnMunsch yes -- you've already accepted an answer to this question, so it should be closed, or made as a comment on the answer rather than an update to the question.  with your update, the accepted answer is no longer accurate for your updated question.  makes it easier for people who might be searching for your original issue to not get confused.

Comment: @JohnMunsch plus, like, more karma for everyone! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick jsFiddle with my version of an answer : http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/3NMGD/

Note: Both the jsFiddle and the code below have been updated to reflect the changed requirements of the question.

```
var model = [
    {
      color: "red",
      age: 10,
      size: [ "small", "large" ]
    },
    {
      color: "red",
      age: 11,
      size: [ "small", "large" ]
    },
    {
      color: "red",
      age: 9,
      size: [ "small", "large" ]
    }
];

function findCommonalities(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        // It's safe enough to get the list of keys from the very first
        // element. If the later ones differ, you know that the keys they
        // had but the first element didn't are guaranteed not to be in
        // the common set anyway because the first element didn't
        // have them.
        var keys = _.keys(data[0]);
        var commonalities = { };

        _.each(keys,
            function (key) {
                var values = _.pluck(data, key);

                if (values.length == data.length) {
                    // Sadly calling _.uniq() won't work when the values
                    // plucked out are arrays themselves. It calls ===
                    // and that's not sufficient for arrays.
                    if (_.isArray(values[0])) {
                        // However, we can get a little tricky here.
                        // What if we _.zip() together all of the arrays
                        // (assuming the ordering for each array is the
                        // same) then we'll end up with an array of
                        // arrays where each one can again be tested
                        // with _.uniq() because each one will contain
                        // the same value taken from each array.
                        var zippedValues = _.zip(values);
                        console.log("zippedValues", zippedValues);

                        if (!_.find(zippedValues,
                            function (zippedValue) {
                                var uniqueValues = _.uniq(zippedValue);

                                // Note: This test is the inverse of the
                                // one below. We're trying to find any
                                // array that has more than one value in
                                // it. If we do then there's some
                                // variance.
                                return uniqueValues.length != 1;
                            })) {
                            // We didn't find any arrays that had any
                            // variance so we want this as well.
                            commonalities[key] = values[0];
                        }
                    } else {
                        var uniqueValues = _.uniq(values);

                        if (uniqueValues.length == 1) {
                            commonalities[key] = uniqueValues[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        return commonalities;
    } else {
        return { };
    }
}

console.log("commonalities: ", findCommonalities(model));
```

Performance seems fine with a small number of keys and a small number of items, but you'd need to test it with a million records and a large number of keys.

Comment: I was trying to add a solution but my approach was a little mess :)

Comment: @John Munsch - this solution is fantastic.  One final piece - my requirements have changed and now some attributes of an object can be arrays.  I'm updating my question, but is there a way to modify your solution to compare properties that are arrays?

Comment: @Kevin Whitaker Updated to reflect your changed requirements. Sadly it's not nearly as graceful anymore and about twice as long :( Perhaps someone else can suggest a better solution than the first one that occurred to me.

Comment: @JohnMunsch That is awesome.  I wish I could vote more than once. Many thanks!

Comment: How about compare the attributes of the model and get the differences between them?